# Fontello icon alias

Tags: html, fontello

I'm creating website and I have a little issue. For every name for class or ID, I used camelCase, but fontello icon always have syntaxes: icon-something. Is there a way to create alias to icon, smg like iconSomething?

Comment: Can you edit your question and be clearer about what kinds of identifiers that icon pack brings? What do they look like, how do you use them? Also this probably needs the `css` tag

Answer (score 2):

**Fontello CSS Prefix**

Fontello has a built-in setting that allows you to change the css prefix from `icon-` to an alternative. On Fontello.com at the top of the page, there is a square button with a wrench on it. When you click on that button, you will be presented with a text-field that allows you to change the `icon-` css prefix. It's also worth noting that the `-` is not required.